# Defining and non-defining relative clauses with proper nouns

Tags: grammaticality

I've been looking at analysing a text and have been examining convention vs correct grammar and function when looking at nominal groups and proper nouns as non-defining relative clauses. As a convention we write the sentence:

My brother, John, is fun.

Analysed it is:

My brother, // John, // is fun.

I'm not sure if the commas are convention as there is a change in meaning with:

My brother John is fun.

Analysed:

My brother [[John]] is fun.

This includes *John* in the *My brother* nominal group. This is most likely how we mean it to function. I can understand the elaboration of *John* to *My friend* as non defining with the ellipsis of *who is named* making it a relative clause. I am unsure as to whether that is how it functions. Logically *My brother* is head noun, but it is interesting that a proper noun isn't defining.

Are the commas conventions and proper nouns used with commas functionally embedded?

Thanks, I've been in this rabbit hole for a few days now...

Comment: No, it's not some kind of relative clause. "John" is an appositive noun phrase in both cases. The difference is that in "my brother, John, is fun", we understand that you have only one brother, so "John" is supplementary appositive - a specifying noun phrase - that can be substituted for the whole supplementation yielding an entailment of the original, i.e. "John is fun". Without the comma, as in "My brother John is fun", we understand that you have more than one brother, so here "John" is an integrated (restrictive) appositive functioning as modifier of "brother".

Comment: The parenthetical is grammatically different being that. OTOH, "My brother John is fun" uses *My brother* as noun adjunct to *brother* and at the same time shifts focus from *My brother* to "John".

Comment: @Kris No, "My brother" is a genitive noun phrase serving as subject.

Comment: @BillJ In which case?

Comment: @Kris In the restrictive "My brother John is fun", the subject is the genitive NP "my brother John", where the appositive noun "John" modifies "brother". In the non-restrictive "My brother, John, is fun", the subject is the genitive NP "my brother". Here, "John" is not a modifier but a supplement, a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary non-integrated content, set off with commas and a slight pause in speech.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. They are very helpful.

Comment: I think I understand this some more, however, how is this treated in a functional grammar analysis? From Halliday: "Prepositional phrases, nominal clauses and defining relative clauses are typical embedded constructions because they expand meaning of a previous noun phrase by giving more information about it."